# To override existing select2 multiselect dropdown with new data using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, jquery-select2, dropdown

I have two Select2 multiselect dropdown which has a parent child relationship. The first dropdown consists of countries and the second consists of cities. Both drop downs on initial load are populated using Razor.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 right">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Countries) :
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.DropDownList("Countries", Model.CountriesList, new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 right">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.City) :
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.ListBox("city", Model.CityList, new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
            </div>
    </div>
</div>


 $('#Countries').select2({
    placeholder: "Select Country..."
 });

 $('#city').select2({
     placeholder: "Select City..."
 });
```

This portion works fine. Now on selection of the dropdown countries, I have to populate the cities accordingly. Since the countries and cities are static data I do not want to use AJAX and constant server calls for this.

```
const countrycitylist = {
    "Australia": [
        { id: "syd", text: "Sydney" }, { id: "mlb", text: "Melbourne" }
    ],
    "Cannada": [
        { id: "tor", text: "Toronto" }, { id: "mon", text: "Montreal" }
    ],
    "Newzealand" : [
        { id: "auk", text: "Auckland" }, { id: "wel", text: "Welington" }
    ]
};

$("#Countries").on("change", function () {
    var country = $(this).val(); // Selected values are Australia and Cannada
    var lstCity = [];
    if (country != null || country != undefined) {

        if (country.length > 1) {
            $("#city").select2("destroy");
            for (var key in countrycitylist ) {
                if (country.includes(key)) {
                    lstCity  = lstCity.concat(countrycitylist [key])
                }
            }
            $('#city').select2({
                data: lstCity 
            });
        }

    }
    else {
        return;
    }
});
```

So basically I am trying to append into lstcity all the key value pair and make it one single list to populate the dropdown.

The value of lstCity on the console is

```
0:{id: "syd", text: "Sydney"}
1:{id: "mlb", text: "Melbourne"}
2:{id: "tor", text: "Toronto"}
3:{id: "mon", text: "Montreal"}
length:4
__proto__:Object
```

But the select2 dropdown still retains it's initial value from the initial load and there is no change in spite of me manually destroying and rebuilding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to trigger change to change the values of the select2 dropdown.

Your code should be

```
$('#city').select2({
                       data: lstCity 
                   }).trigger("change");
```

This will add the 4 items at the end of the existing list.

If your intention is to wipe the list off and populate only those 4 then you will have to empty it before binding the new data

```
$('#city').empty().trigger("change");
$('#city').select2({
                       data: lstCity 
                   }).trigger("change");
```